# 5 seconds delay(pause) from django+apache

Tags: mysql, django, apache

I am running a site with django+apache+ssl+mysql+cloudfron+s3.

However, I discovered that the ttfb time increases significantly when the first connection and caching setup time ends at some point.
(response starts after pause for about 5 seconds)

After uninstalling Apache, I tried debugging in debug mode and in Gunicorn.

There were no issues with ttfb in debug mode. However, I found out that I had the same problem when using Gunicorn.

So I looked all over apache, db, ssl, django template rendering, etc.

I don't know what's causing the bottleneck.

Which part should I look at more?

Oh, and I also found that if I send a request twice in a row, I get a response right away without any pause.

Please advise. I think my head is going to break...

edit : I tested it without any cdn or database page, but the result was the same.

Comment: Is the first request slow no matter which view you hit? Are you running some query or other IO when your app loads? Can you delete your local database and run `manage.py check` and see if you get an `OperationalError` regarding a table not existing

Comment: Try hitting a route that instantly returns a response without using any cdn or database calls. See if your ttfb time is high.

Comment: @Jae  I tested it without any cdn or database page, but the result was the same.

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes. No matter which view hit, it becomes a bottleneck. and not running query or other IO when app loads

Comment: @moogstar are you using a something similar to a spot instance or something similar where the instance has to spin up before running?